# Determine all complex numbers $z$ for an inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

> Determine all complex numbers $z$ for which $|2z-1| \le 2|z-i|$.

Can someone please help me with this question? I'm not sure how to start it off. Its not a homework question, its on an exam preparation question sheet and I really need help! Thanks!

Comment: Think to the geometric meaning of $|z-1/2| \le |z-i|$. Recall that $|z-w|$ is the euclidean distance between $z$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $|2z-1| \le 2|z-i|$ is equivalent with $|2z-1|^2 \le 4|z-i|^2$.

Now use, that for a complex number $w$ we have $|w|^2=w \overline{w}$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I now have 4z^2-4z+1≤2z^2-4zi-2 and I'm not sure how to continue on.

Answer (score 0):

let $z=a+bi$ then you will get
$$|2(a+bi)-1|\le 2|a+bi-i|$$ or
$$\sqrt{(2a-1)^2+4b^2}\le 2\sqrt{a^2+(b-1)^2}$$
simplifying we get $$3+4a-8b\geq 0$$